# How to add a line under ggplot axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a pair of horizontal lines at the bottom of ggplot to illustrate grouping of the x axis elements. It looks like both `geom_abline` and `geom_segment` will add lines inside the graph. Any idea how to add lines under it ?

```
p + geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = -0.5, xend = 4, yend = -0.5 )) +
        geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = -0.5, xend = 7, yend = -0.5))
```

this plots the line segment within the plot not under the axis title.

Comment: ggplot alone can only do annotations within the plot area, but several extension packages let you annotate outside the plot area. I know `cowplot` can do this, there may be other packages that can too

Comment: Thanks for the information. The answer below is useful, but I will keep your comment in mind and try `cowplot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make annotations outside the plot area by using `coord_cartesian(xlim, ylim, clip="off")` and then using `annotate()` with the appropriate geom. Depending on your aesthetic for grouping, you can put lines at the base of the plot area or below the axis labels.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10), y=seq(1,10))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), clip="off") +
  annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 4, y = -1, yend = -1) +
  annotate("segment", x = 5, xend = 7, y = -0.5, yend = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @PDM, My pleasure. For future reference, the same approach can be applied to different geoms in a variety of applications as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079210/how-can-i-add-annotations-below-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2/53531754#53531754) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354718/how-to-change-x-axis-labels-in-ggboxplot/54356362#54356362).